# Problema mostrando una posición específica de un arreglo usando una variable C++

Tags: c++, array, bucles

Me mandaron a hacer un programa (c++) en la universidad que pida al usuario una cantidad de **n** productos, luego pedirle que llene esa cantidad, como un carrito de compra, con los siguientes datos:

***Nombre, Cantidad, Precio Unitario, Precio Total (Precio Unitario * Cantidad)*.**

Después de llenar todo, el programa debe mostrar en orden todos los productos ingresados con su respectivo numero y nombre y que el usuario pueda detallar cualquier producto ingresando el numero del mismo. He utilizado las siguientes variables como vectores para llenar cada uno de los datos

```
string nombre[n];
int cantidad[n];
float precio[n];
float precioTotal[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout << "\n\t\tArticulo " << i+1 << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: "; cin >> nombre[i];
    cout << "Cantidad: "; cin >> cantidad[i];
    cout << "Precio: "; cin >> precio[i];
    precioTotal[i] = cantidad[i] * precio[i];
}//for
```

Luego muestro una pequeña lista con el numero y el nombre del producto con un ciclo for.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << i+1 << ". " << nombre[i] << endl;           
    }//for
```

Despues de esto he creado una variable ***a*** como auxiliar, para que el usuario ingrese cual producto desea detallar, y por ultimo muestro los vectores con la posicion ***a*** de esta forma:

```
    cout << "\nIngrese el numero de un producto para mostrar detalles: "; cin >> a;     
    cout << "\n\tArticulo numero: " << a << endl << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: " << nombre[a] << endl;
    cout << "Cantidad: " << cantidad[a] << endl;
    cout << "Precio Unitario: " << precio[a] << endl;
    cout << "Precio Total: " << precioTotal[a]  << endl;
```

Mi problema es que al hacer todo esto, al llegar a la linea donde muestro el **nombre[a]**, el programa entra en un loop infinito que hace saltos de línea. He probado comentar esta línea para ver que sucede, y el programa muestra el resto de los datos en 0 sin importar que dato ingrese el usuario.

Otra cosa, si en vez de usar la variable ***a*** pongo cualquier numero entero:

```
cantidad[0];
precio[0];
precioTotal[0];
```

El programa muestra los valores correctos, he intentado además incializar todas las variables en 0, incluso todas las posiciones de cada vector en 0, y el error persiste. Que puedo hacer en este caso?

***Ejemplo Minimo Completo y Verificable:***

```
int n,i,a=0;
cout << "Digite la cantidad de productos a ingresar: "; cin >> n;

string nombre[n];
int cantidad[n];
float precio[n];
float precioTotal[n];

//Pedir valores
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout << "\n\t\tArticulo " << i+1 << endl;
    cout << "Nombre: "; cin >> nombre[i];
    cout << "Cantidad: "; cin >> cantidad[i];
    cout << "Precio: "; cin >> precio[i];
    precioTotal[i] = cantidad[i] * precio[i];
}//for

system("cls");  

cout << "\t\tLista de Articulos Ingresados" << endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << i << ". " << nombre[i] << endl;         
}//for

//Cambia el nombre[a] a nombre[0] y veras que se quita el error de loop
cout << "\nIngrese el numero de un producto para mostrar detalles: "; cin >> a;             
cout << "Nombre: " << nombre[a] << endl;

getch();
```

Comment: ¿ Estás diciendo que `cout << nombre[0];` muestra un resultado distinto de `int a = 0; cout << nombre[a]` ? Eso es **imposible**.

Comment: Exacto, lo mismo pensaba yo y he revisado el código línea por línea y me sigue dando ese problema. *edito* He probado hacerlo directamente de esa forma, declarando yo mismo un valor a la variable a, y el código funciona y muestra el valor correspondiente. Al parecer el error solo se genera si en vez de declararle un valor a la variable le pido al usuario que le asigne un valor

Comment: Te reto a que proporciones un [mcve] que lo demuestre, porque, insisto: **es imposible**. 100% de probabilidad de que estás inicializando mal tu variable `a` :-)

Comment: He editado el código que has puesto ... pruébalo cuando puedas :-)

Comment: Ya te dije que era **imposible** :-)

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que probé el código que colocas arriba y funciona sin problemas, solo toma en cuenta que los arreglos empiezan desde cero. El otro problema que te esté pasando es que no estés guardando bien la variable a, trata de limpiar el buffer antes de leerla con fflush(stdin), me comentas cómo te va. Prueba en un compilador en línea y funciona bien.